# Allow two clients in a room to video chat (webRTC)

Tags: node.js, socket.io, webrtc

There seems to be a lack of information on the web as to how I may achieve this. If anyone can provide me with references or tutorials that would be great as well.

At the moment, I used socket IO to create a room for each two users that log in to my website. So each room contains two users

I implemented a chat system that allows each two users to talk to each other.

Now, I want to enable video between these two users. I've been looking at tutorial and figured out how to enable the webcam...

```
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
    navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
    navigator.msGetUserMedia;

var video = document.getElementById("video");
var cameraStream = "";

if(navigator.getUserMedia){
    navigator.getUserMedia(
        {audio:false, video:true},
        function(stream){
            cameraStream = stream;
            video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
            video.play();
        },function(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    );
}
else
    alert("getUserMedia not supported!");
```

How can I enable video between two users in a room? Can I do this using the id of the room?

I know this is a broad question but I'm looking for any kind of guidance that will help me implement this.

Comment: The chat system is implemented via socket.io only, or using the WebRTC DataChannel??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are willing to use WebRTC you should check this [HTML5 Rocks' blog post](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/) about it. The 2 main points you need to read there are:

> 1. Get to grips with the RTCPeerConnection API
> 2. Learn more about how WebRTC uses servers for signaling

Also the [official page of WebRTC](https://webrtc.org/start/) is another good resource of knowledge. They have 30+ links with information about every part of the process.

**NOTE:** You can continue using (UDP) sockets to send video streams between browsers. WebRTC is another solution to the problem (a better one in my opinion)

Answer (score 0):

Right now there are two Node.js projects for video chat. Both are experimental, but I've heard they work quite well if you can get them running.

1. *https://github.com/webRTC-io/webrtc.io-client*
2. [*https://github.com/kdomagal/Web-RTC*](https://github.com/kdomagal/Web-RTC) A demo app.

I have also found one blog with the reference of Demo project and working Example.

[***How to create Video Chat application using node.js and socket.io***](https://medium.com/@hirenkavad/how-to-create-video-chat-application-using-node-js-and-socket-io-99e64929969d#.dr4rq62mz).

Hope this is usefull for you.